# xboxdrv to move mouse absolutely

Tags: mouse, joystick

Is it possible to use xbox gamepad and xboxdrv to move the mouse pointer to absolute positions? Especially within a square around the screen's center?

thanks.

Comment: not necessary. Do you suggest calling it constantly?

Answer (score 0):

Found a working config here: https://github.com/xboxdrv/ubuntu/blob/master/examples/absolutemouse.xboxdrv

(but really don't know what every option means ...)

```
[xboxdrv]
dpad-as-button=true

extra-devices=false

[modifier]
square = X1:Y1

[ui-axismap]
X1 = ABS_X
Y1 = ABS_Y
X2^dead:4000 = REL_HWHEEL:5:100
Y2^invert^dead:4000 = REL_WHEEL:5:100
lt = void
rt = void

[ui-buttonmap]
a  = BTN_LEFT
b  = BTN_RIGHT
x  = BTN_MIDDLE
y  = KEY_ENTER
rb = KEY_PAGEDOWN
lb = KEY_PAGEUP

[ui-buttonmap]
dl = KEY_LEFT
dr = KEY_RIGHT
du = KEY_UP
dd = KEY_DOWN

[ui-buttonmap]
start = KEY_FORWARD
back  = KEY_BACK
guide = KEY_ESC

# EOF #
```